# How can I differentiate Hermite polynomial with respect to $n$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I differentiate the function below (where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants) with respect to $n$?

```
D[HermiteH[n, (Sqrt[β] Log[1 + x γ])/γ]/Sqrt[Sqrt[β]/((2^n)*(n!)*Sqrt[Pi])], n]
```

It seems that Mathematica cannot do it.

Comment: In Hermite[n,x] n is assumed to be a non negative Integer. You can not take the derivative relative to n, only relative to x and then it is: D[ Hermite[n,x],x]= 2n  Hermite[n-1,x]

Comment: @DanielHuber Some of the examples in the [Help](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteH.html) demonstrate `HermiteH[1/2, x]`.

Comment: @Ghoster If n is not an integer, H[n,x] is not a polynomial

Comment: @DanielHuber, even if it is not a polynomial, it is still a smooth function: `Plot[HermiteH[n, 1], {n, 0, 3}]` or `Plot3D[HermiteH[n, x], {n, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber Agreed. The title of the question should not call it the Hermite polynomial, and neither should Wolfram’s help page.

Comment: *It seems that Mathematica cannot do it.* Why do you say that? I got a result when I executed your line of code. What result did you get? I don't see any problem with doing this.

Comment: @Ghoster In the resulting expression, this expression appears,
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(HermiteH\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[n, (
 Sqrt[\[Beta]] Log[1 + x \[Gamma]])/\[Gamma]]
which cannot be solved.

Comment: *which cannot be solved* What does that mean? You solve equations, not expressions. Mathematica can evaluate that expression just fine for numerical values.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you believe, incorrectly, that the derivatives of named functions can always be expressed in terms of elementary functions and special functions that have been given names. Nobody has bothered to name the derivative of $H_n(x)$ with respect to $n$. But it still exists as a legitimate function, and probably has integral representations, series representations, etc. If you try differentiating the Riemann zeta function you’ll see that it doesn't have a “simplified” form either. Mathematica just calls it Zeta’(x).

Comment: BTW… The additional info you provided in your comment should be edited into your question.

Comment: Note that `Derivative[1, 0][HermiteH][n, x]` is evaluated by a numerical procedure when `n` or `x` is an approximate number. It can be evaluated to arbitrary precision. It is left unevaluated if `n` and `x` are exact numbers or symbolic expressions. Not every derivative is known in terms of other functions. Finally, it seems Mathematica does not have built-in algorithms to evaluate 2nd and higher order derivatives of `HermitH[n, x]` with respect to `n`.

Comment: `D[HermiteH[n, x], n]`: what result do you expect? Give as a solution?

Comment: The Hermite polynomials are special solutions to the ODE  $$-f'' + x^2 f  == (2p+1) f$$ with p a positive integer. The general solution is the $$e^{-x^2/4} D_p{x)$$ with parabolic cylinder functions. These are special cases of confluent hypergeometric or Whitacker functions, that have no known derivatives with respect to the parameters, more so because the integer cases ar special limits of $\Phi$ and $\Psi$, the two independent solutions of the ODE, that become dependent for integer parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative is an exact expression. To evaluate further, you must provide numeric input.

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dHn[β_, γ_, n_, x_] = 
 D[HermiteH[n, (Sqrt[β] Log[1 + x γ])/γ]/
    Sqrt[Sqrt[β]/((2^n)*(n!)*Sqrt[Pi])], n] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1234];

dHn @@ RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 4]
```

[image]

```
% // N

(* -16367.9 *)

dHn @@ RandomReal[1, 4]

(* -0.606802 *)
```